# Load and continue running from the epoch at which they stopped

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm training a huge model. Unfortunately, the runtime environment breaks off about halfway and I have to restart the model.I save the model after each epoch.

But my question now is, for example, I've trained 5 out of 10 epcohs.
How do I load it and indicate that I was at the 5th epoch and that he has to continue there so only has to go through 5 epochs? I know that I can load the model, but how can I say I was at the 5 epoch and now you only have to go through 5 epochs because I wanted a total of 10.

```
cp_callback = [tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath='/saved/model.h5', 
    verbose=1, 
    save_weights_only=True,
    save_freq= 'epoch'),
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=2)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save epoch number in a separate file (pickle or json file).

```
import json

train_parameters = {'iter': iteration, 'batch_size': batch_size'}

# saving

json.dump(trainParameters, open(output_path+"trainParameters.txt",'w'))

# loading

trainParameters = json.load(open(path_to_saved_model+"trainParameters.txt"))
input = tf.random.uniform([8, 24], 0, 100, dtype=tf.int32)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=training_loss, metrics=evaluation_accuracy)
hist = model.fit((input, input), input, epochs=1,
                        steps_per_epoch=1, verbose=0)
model.load_weights(path_to_saved_model+'saved.h5')
```

But if you need to save learning rate step - save optimizer state. The state contain iteration number (number of batches passed).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! 
I would like to save it in such a way that I only have to load it and it recognizes how many epochs it was in and with which parameters. Is there anything like that?

Comment: the model doesn't keep this information. Optimizer keeps iteration number only. Neither model nor optimizer use epoch number in calculations. And they just can not access it - they only see batches on the input

Comment: Setting the batch_size as a parameter would also be no problem.

But if I train with 5 epochs, save it and then change my parameter epcohs to 5, does it continue training on the 5 epochs from before?

Comment: unless you are using learning rate schedule - starting epoch doesn't affect training

Comment: I found this `If you are using TF or Keras to train your model there is a Model Checkpoint callback available which you can use to save your model while training and when your session ends then you can just load the last saved model and continue training.`.  
But unfortunately there is no such option?

Comment: When you load model from checkpoint - you will not lose your training until saving. And can continue training from the saved point. But the checkpoint doesn't keep information about the epoch number. You need to save it separately.

Comment: Thank you for your patience!  I would then save the Batch_size separately.  could you show me how to save it and load it again and continue training from the Stores file?

Comment: thank you! 
With this I save the parameters.

And how do I load the model? I have already saved it with my callbacks and now just have to load it and continue training.

Comment: try to call model.load_weights(). You have to first create model, then compile it, then build it (just call with dummy input) and then call load_weights. It should work. I don't use callback for saving though. So I am not 100% sure.

Comment: thank you very much! Do you have for that a code snippet please?

Comment: You're the best! Wish you all the best. Thank you.